# echo out all favourites that belong to the users profile in mysql and identify the users profile by url?

Tags: php, mysql

hi can someone please help me. i am echoing out a users favourites onto their profile, and to save space i am limiting the query to three user favourites/results on the profile page.

I am then placing a hyperlink which can be clicked by the user to show all that users favourites belonging to that profile id onto another page. The link they click echoe's the profile_id of the user and the 2nd query 'get_user_favourites_more' should then echo out all the favourites that belong to the profile they've just hyperlinked from (the profile_id thats been echoed through the link.)

i am not getting any results echoed from mysql function. the the profile_id is being echoed successfully as i am placing the profile_id number in the the title of the page. its just not echoing out the favourites that belong to that user.

i need to somehow set the 2nd mysql query to say identify the favourites that belong to the user_id and get user_id from url? (i think?)

Can someone please show me how i can get this to do what i want thanks.

mysql query 1:

```
function get_favourites() {
            global $connection;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "SELECT e.fav_id
                        FROM ptb_user_favourites e
                        WHERE e.user_id =\"$profile_id\"
                        AND e.approved = '1'
                        LIMIT 3";
                        $favourites_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($favourites_set);
            return $favourites_set;

        }
```

the users profile that lists the three first results/users favourites:

```
<div class="prof-favourites-box2"><div class="show_more_favourites"><a href="show_all_favourites.php?to=<?php echo "$profile_id"; ?>">show all favourites ></a></div></div>
<?php
        $favourites_set = get_favourites();
        $duo_count = mysql_num_rows($favourites_set);
while ($fav = mysql_fetch_array($favourites_set)) {

    echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$fav['fav_id']}\"><img width=\"60px\" height=\"60px\" class=\"escort_duo_pic\" src=\"data/photos/{$fav['fav_id']}/_default.jpg\" /></a>";
```

show all favourites function/2nd query:

```
function get_favourites_more() {
            global $connection;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "SELECT e.fav_id
                        FROM ptb_user_favourites e
                        WHERE e.user_id =\"$profile_id\"
                        AND e.approved = '1'";
                        $get_favourites_more = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($get_favourites_more);
            return $get_favourites_more;

        }
```

my show all favourites page/the page the user links to from the users profile:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset ($_GET['to'])) {
$user_to_id = $_GET['to'];


}


if (!isset($_GET['to']))
    exit('No user specified.');

$user_id = $_GET['to']; ?>

<?php
        $favourites_more_set = get_favourites_more();
        while ($fav = mysql_fetch_array($favourites_more_set)) {
            $date = age_from_dob($fav['dob']);

            echo"
            <div class=\"boxgrid caption\">
            <a href=\"profile.php?id={$fav['id']}\"><img width=140px height= 180px src=\"data/photos/{$fav['id']}/_default.jpg\"/></a>
            <div class=\"cover boxcaption\">
            <h58> {$fav['display_name']}, ".$date."</h58>
            </div>
            </div>";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would usually do is set a session with id when a user logs in. And use that is to carry out all all user related searches like where session = Session_id.

But in your case, it seems that your profile id in the URL is set to fav_id. Though I personally feel it is unorthodox, I suggest you do a $profile_id = $_GET['to']; and URL set to profile.php?user_id=$profile_id

Let me know if it works. Sorry I can't write comments yet. Also are there any errors showing?